# why using a dictionary in a recursion leads to mistakes-python?

Tags: python, function, dictionary, recursion

I want to make a program in python where you give a target word and an array of words and check if it possible to make the target word using the words from the array. Also I want to return all the possible ways.

```
def allConstruct(target,wordBank):   
    if target=='': return [[]]
    can=[]
    for word in wordBank:
        if target.find(word)==0 :
            suffix=target[len(word):]
            suffixways=allConstruct(suffix,wordBank)
            for lis in suffixways:
                lis.insert(0,word)
            can.extend(suffixways)
    return can
print(allConstruct('purple',['purp','p','ur','le','purpl']))
```

If you run this program you get [['purp', 'le'], ['p', 'ur', 'p', 'le']] which is correct. Now trying to make it more efficient, I introduce a dictionary.

```
def allConstruct(target,wordBank, memo=None):    
    if memo is None: memo={}
    if target in memo: return memo[target]
    if target=='': return [[]]

    can=[]
    for word in wordBank:
        if target.find(word)==0 :
            suffix=target[len(word):]
            suffixways=allConstruct(suffix,wordBank,memo)
            for lis in suffixways:
                lis.insert(0,word)
            can.extend(suffixways)
    memo[target]=can

    return can
print(allConstruct('purple',['purp','p','ur','le','purpl']))
```

The result here is [['p', 'ur', 'p', 'purp', 'le'], ['p', 'ur', 'p', 'purp', 'le']].
In fact, the memo at the first step is {'le': [['le']]} and then it becomes {'le': [['p', 'purp', 'le']], 'ple': [['p', 'purp', 'le']]}. I do not understand why the value for 'le' changes as the program runs. Can you help me undertand this? Thank you very much!

Comment: @CryptoFool was on the right track, but insufficiently deep enough of a copy, as it is a list of list and a deep copy is needed.  Since this is only two levels deep the memo should just be updated using `memo[target] = [c.copy() for c in can]`.

Comment: Ha.  I realized that right away, but decided to make it an answer instead as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! Indeed, now we get the correct result. But I still have a question. When I print `memo`, I see that the value of 'le' is changing after every iteration, i.e {'le': [['le']]},  {'le': [['p', 'le']], 'ple': [['p', 'le']]}, {'le': [['ur', 'p', 'le']], 'ple': [['p', 'le']], 'urple': [['ur', 'p', 'le']]} etc. Is this supposed to happen, or we should always have {'le': [['le']]} ?

Comment: To answer my question: I need to store the values even earlier in order for them not to change. In the code, I need to add an extra line at @CryptoFool 's answer, after defining 
 suffixways, and a few modifications:  Add
 `SUFFIXways=copy.deepcopy(suffixways)`  and then use only SUFFIXways instead of suffixways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is due to the fact that you are adding lists to `memo` that you then go on and modify.  Look at the end of your function.  You set `memo[target]=can` and then you return `can`.  But now look at what happens in the calling version of the function.  It assigns the result of the inner call to the variable `suffixways` and then goes on and modifies the values in that list.  You don't want to do that.  You need to put values into `memo` that aren't going to change. You can do that with `copy.deepcopy()`

```
import copy

def allConstruct(target,wordBank, memo=None):
    if memo is None: memo={}
    if target in memo: return memo[target]
    if target=='': return [[]]

    can=[]
    for word in wordBank:
        if target.find(word)==0:
            suffix=target[len(word):]
            suffixways=allConstruct(suffix,wordBank,memo)
            for lis in suffixways:
                lis.insert(0,word)
            can.extend(suffixways)
    memo[target]=copy.deepcopy(can)
    return can

print(allConstruct('purple',['purp','p','ur','le','purpl']))
```

Result:

```
[['purp', 'le'], ['p', 'ur', 'p', 'le']]
```

This is the same result as what you get with your first version.